# What is the word for "changing values of a set, but not order"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that roughly means "changing values of a set, but not order". I have been wrongly using "Permutation" or "Permutate", but that means changing the order of a collection, not the values if I'm correct. I'm writing a program that, each loop, changes the values of a collection (according to some rules) and renders the resulting image. What would that action be called?

Example:

`[1.2, 2.3, 0, 1]` -> `[1.2, 2.5, 1, 0]`

Sample Sentence:

*"Each loop, the collection of parameters is **xxx** and a new image is rendered"*

I've tried looking [here](https://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=change%20value%20of) using "change value of" but haven't really found anything satisfactory. A single word is what I'm looking for...I really hope there is one.

Comment: Are the new values calculated from the previous values? If so I'd call that "transformation".

Comment: If not, "insertion", since they come from somewhere else.

Comment: @nnnnnn not really, I randomize them now. But they don't necessarily have to be randomized...

Comment: *Permute* is to swap positions; *transmute* is to change in place. Maybe.

Comment: in your example how can we tell that you’ve changed the third one to 1 and the fourth one to zero and not swapped the order?

Comment: "Substitute" might work for you. I would tend to use that for a one-value-at-a-time replacement rather than a wholesale replacement of the entire set where the suggestion of "inserted" by @JohnLawler is probably better. The trouble with "inserted" for a single value is that it implies the addition of an extra one. The only difficulty with "substitute" is that "A is substituted for B" is sometimes used to mean that A replaces B (which I and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substitute) consider to be correct) but is sometimes taken to mean that B replaces A:-?

Answer (score 3):

"Set" normally implies unordered collections.

The parameters are used to *apply* or *map* a transformation/function over the values. If the original value is changed, rather than a new one produced, it is *mutated*.

Comment: You're right about that. I just used the word to mean a collection of N numbers. Mutated isn't bad...